# How can I know what is the cause of linux to crash at start-up?

Tags: gentoo, crash

I'm using gentoo. Sometimes (not always), when the system starts (from power up), its crash (before I'm getting the GUI login window).

I know Linux saves into log files the problem of the crash, but I'm so confuse and don't know from where to start ?

```
Do I Need to check the dmsg file ? (or other log file ?)
Do I need to grep with "errors" ? or there string pattern to search in the dmsg or other logging file ?)
```

Comment: Since the log files usually have time stamps on their entries, looking for the time of the crash would be the first I'd do.

Comment: You could look for errors inside the kernel log file (/var/log/kern.log). If your OS stops booting you can use a live usb to access your main OS files. Or if your GUI is broken you can access other terminals with <Ctrl><Alt><F1>.

Comment: If you are using OpenRC (as opposed to systemd), you can enable interactive boot by opening the file `/etc/rc.conf` and uncommenting the line that says: `#rc_interactive="YES"`. Then, next time you boot up, hit I after it prompts you and you can manually control which services start. This might help you pinpoint where the crash occurs. As long as a logger daemon (metalog, syslog-ng, etc.) starts before the crash, there might also be some clues in your `/var/log` directory. If it happens as soon as the XDM service starts, you might want to start looking for video card compatibility issues.

Answer (score 1):

It depends at which stage crash takes place. It can be kernel problem, eg. wrong/conflicted parameters passed to it as an options in the grub config, or (most probable) problems with missed or wrongly configured system packages.

It also depends which `init` system do you use. If it is `openrc` then first step is to check /var/log/messages for errors, if you use rather `systemd` then `journalctl` command is your friend (here usually errors are marked red).

Of course `dmesg | less` command can be helpful as well.

If your boot process stops and you cannot see `X` (GUI) login screen then maybe it is just misconfigured Xorg/gnome/gdm/whatever. Then just hit <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to login at console. In case even that is not possible then you can try to boot linux as a single user, the so called rescue mode. Here are the steps to do that:

> 1. At grub level select the kernel you want to boot, but instead of
>      enter hit 'e' (edit)
> 2. Select the line starting with word 'kernel' and again hit 'e'
> 3. Add letter 'S' at the end of the line
> 4. Press ENTER and 'b' (boot)

You will now boot at very minimal system just to login as a root and get a few commands available to figure out what is going on with your gentoo.